# Deal with async/Task for call a RESTful web service in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin.forms, async-await, task

I've to call a RESTful web service in my Xamarin Forms app.
I'd like to add an Activity Indicator in order to avoid user actions while web service call is running; so I think that I've to use C# async/Task, correct?

The web service that I've to consume is an existing one then I've to follow previous specification. In this case I've to execute the login that is composed by two steps. In the first one I've to get the real base url of by POSTing to a fixed url and after POST user credentials to an url composed by the returned url + a fixed part.

I made some try and what I see is that the string where I want to store the web service response content is empty becouse the code continues to run even if web service call is not finished and I don't know how to deal it.

Here is my code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

public async Task<string> Post(string url, FormUrlEncodedContent parameters)
{
    using (var response = await client.PostAsync(url, parameters))
    {
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    };        
} 

// Used to bind ActivityIndicator IsRunning property in XAML file
public string ShowActivityIndicator { get; set; }

public async void ButtonClickMethod()
{
    ShowActivityIndicator = true;

    await GetLink();
    var user = await GetLink();

    ShowActivityIndicator = false;

    App.Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage(user));
}

public string BaseUrl { get; set; }
public string LoginUrl { get { return BaseUrl + Constants.LoginUrlPart; }

public async Task GetLink(FormUrlEncodedContent parameters)
{
    var json = await Post(Constants.LinkUrl, parameters);

    // json is empty becouse web service call hasn't yet finished
    var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Link>(json);

    BaseUrl = response.Link;
}

public async Task<User> Login(FormUrlEncodedContent parameters)
{
    var json = await Post(LoginUrl);

    // json is empty becouse web service call hasn't yet finished
    var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);

    return response;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but why not use a library like [Refit](https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit) to do this a lot easier?

Comment: I remember that I tried some third parties library to consume this web service (I think that I also tried Refit but I'm not sure) the returned JSON wasn't the expected. The only one that returned the correct response was RestSharp but it hasn't a PCL version. The web service is developed in PHP using CodeIgniter framework, don't know if I've to take some particular shrewdness for consume it.

Comment: Another thing that I about the web service is that I've to use `FormUrlEncodedContent` to pass parameters, before I tried with `StringContent` and the responses weren't as expected.

Comment: I'm confused by your code. Your first `Login` calls `GetLink` twice, without any parameters, when `GetLink` requires a parameter and your second `Login` is never called. Could you fix the code, so that it at least compiles?

Comment: @YiyiChen: If `json` is empty where the comments indicate, then the web service returned an empty string. The web service call *has* completed at that point.

Comment: Sorry, I made some mistake in posted code, now i renamed `Login()` in `ButtonClickMethod()`. In my project I binded the `LoginPage` button with the  `public ICommand LoginCommand { get; internal set; }` that has been initialized in the page constructor `LoginCommand = new Command(ButtonClickMethod)`. Hope that now the process is more clear.

Comment: @StephenCleary: Are you sure? I seem to remember when I debugged it that the break point on `var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json)` occurs before than `return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` in `Post` method. Anyway I will retry later.

Comment: @YiyiChen I agree with Stephen Cleary's comment. Once the await call has finished, you basically have finished your service call.

Comment: When debugging I would put a breakpoint right after the return await and hit continue. If your json/response is indeed empty at this point it doesn't mean that your method is executing before the await has completed, it means you are returning an empty string. I would use Fiddler or something similar to analyse the call and make sure everything is being sent/returned correctly.

Comment: @YiyiChen: Yes, I'm sure. Execution cannot move past the `await` point until its task has completed. That's the entire purpose of `await`.

Comment: I made some other test and debug. Yes, you are right. Thank you.